# NSURL won't init from string to remote font file (.TTF)

Tags: ios, file, swift, fonts, nsurl

I am trying to load fonts dynamically in my app, given a provided URL path to font files that are hosted on my server.
For some reason, NSURL will not initialize from a valid font file path (http:// www. mydomain.com/my-font-file.ttf - spaces inserted for SO limitations)

This code hits the fail statement every time even when pointing to a completely valid font file located on my server:

```
if let fontUrl = NSURL(string: fontUrlString)
{
     ...handle font saving here...
}
else
{
     println("Failed to create Font URL from string: \(fontUrlString)")
}
```

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Again, copying the logged 'fontUrlString' to my web browser loads the font file and saves it just fine. The font file is also a .TTF file and not corrupt in any way (I can install on my machine the browser downloaded font just fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to load fonts dynamically in my app, given a provided URL path to font files that are hosted on my server

You can't. You can include a font in your app bundle, and you can download a font from Apple by calling `CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler`. But you can't install into your app an arbitrary font downloaded from the Internet while the app runs. That would be a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

```
let s = "http://example.com/my-font-file.ttf"

if let url = NSURL(string: s) {
    println(url)
} else {
    println("Error")
}
```

Are you sure that you don't have any spaces in the name, for example after the ttf?